# Web based media viewer (docs, images, videos) recommendations?

Tags: media

I'm looking for a general purpose media player for my website. I have lots of links to docs, images, videos, mp3s etc. When the user clicks on one of the links, I'd like some sort of viewer to pop up and show the contents, e.g. if its a mp3 it will play the mp3 etc.

I'm aware of the yahoo media player for audio (http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/), and things like yoxview (http://yoxigen.com/yoxview/Default.aspx) for images.

Has anybody had any experience with using any of these? Are there any general purpose viewers that will do all file formats, or is it a matter of integrating a few different ones like those above on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a few that offered what I was looking for:

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

http://embedit.in/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need separate viewers for audio, video, and images.

For anything other than those three, you're best off just serving the file directly the the client.  Users would prefer to open a document in their word processor than play with it in some web based viewer.

If you really want to push the issue you may be able to push documents over to Google Docs and view them there the way GMail does, but I'm not sure if there is an external API to support that.

Comment: Thanks. The user also has the option to download it, but I wanted to also give them the option to view it in the browser without having to download it.